# Create function to count number of web sessions in dataframe per unique ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I've got a dataframe structured in the following way:

| timestamp | participant id | upstream | downstream |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.2020 | person 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1.2.2020 | person 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 1.2.2020 | person 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 2 | 1 | 0 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 2 | 1 | 1 |
| 1.2.2020 | person 2 | 1 | 0 |

I'm looking to create a function which creates a cumulative count of sessions per person. A new session starts when upstream = 1 and downstream = 0.

The ideal output is this:

| timestamp | participant id | session |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1.1.2020 | person 1 | 1 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 1 | 1 |
| 1.2.2020 | person 1 | 2 |
| 1.2.2020 | person 1 | 2 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 2 | 1 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 2 | 1 |
| 1.1.2020 | person 2 | 2 |

What I've attempted so far is;

```
    if (s['upstream']==1 and s['downstream']==1):
        return 1
```

But i'm unsure how to get this to give a cumulative count specific to each person. So when there is a new person identifier, the count restarts to 0.

Any help much appreciated, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["session"] = df["upstream"].eq(1) & df["downstream"].eq(0)
df["session"] = df.groupby("participant id", as_index=False)["session"].cumsum()
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  timestamp participant id  upstream  downstream  session
0  1.1.2020       person 1         1           0        1
1  1.1.2020       person 1         1           1        1
2  1.2.2020       person 1         1           0        2
3  1.2.2020       person 1         1           1        2
4  1.1.2020       person 2         1           0        1
5  1.1.2020       person 2         1           1        1
6  1.2.2020       person 2         1           0        2
```

Comment: You could groupby the series to avoid two assignments -> `df["session"] = (df["upstream"].eq(1) & df["downstream"].eq(0)).groupby(df["participant id"]).cumsum()`